# Reloading DIV (site) prevents further OnClick-handlers + visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM like this:

```
<div class="inner-content">
    <div class="catalogue" style="display: none;">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- some dom here -->
            <button type="button" id="updateCatalogue">
        </div>
    <span class="addNewRow" data-row="1">add new row</span>
</div>
```

I also have a JS-function which triggers correctly, when clicking "click new row". Have a look here:

```
$('.addNewRow').click(function() {

    // determine closest wrapper
    var wrapper = $(this).closest(".questions");
    var kategorieId = $(this).data("row");

    // add another row
    $("<div class='question_wrapper'><input type='text' class='textinput_questions new_question' data-category='"+kategorieId+"' name='new_question["+kategorieId+"][]'><input type='checkbox' class='radioinput' style='margin-left: 6px !important;' name='new_questionActive[]'>").insertAfter(".question_wrapper:last");
});
```

This code works perfectly fine when I open my site and navigate manually to the DIV I'm currently in. Worth mentioning, I'm doing a bit ajax-stuff, which I guess is part of the problem:

```
$('#updateCatalogue').click(function() {

    // inserting stuff 
    $('.new_question').each(function() {
        data = "some data";
        $.ajax({
            url: "my-file.asp",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(question);

                // reload the frame afterwards
                $(".inner-content").load(location.href + " #catalogue");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The part in the `updateCatalogue`-function is processed correctly and the code inside `my-file.asp` is doing its job as well. But as soon as the page "reloads", I can't click on "add new row" anymore... or more like, it doesn't do anything after that. No JS errors in my console.

Since I'm reloading the whole page, I should have access to everything, right?

> Sidenote: These functions are in $(document).ready() if this is important for that

These elements **are not** dynamically created (I guess), since the site is reloaded, even though trough an ajax-call

Comment: but these aren't "dyncamically created", since the page is reloaded before, so they already exist in the dom.

Comment: It's similar to the other, but not an exact duplicate. It's different enough to warrant it's own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, when you use `$('selector').click()`, it only sets up the click event the first time through. If you rebuild that, then it loses it's `click()`.

You can just move your `$('selector').click()` bit to where you create them, but the better solution is to instead use `$(document).on()` instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.addNewRow', function () {
    // do something here
});
```

You would just change your first code block to that. By putting the click event on the `document` (which is everything on the page), instead of the specific elements, it won't be lost if those elements change or go away. The second parameter then provides a filter selector, which is the same you would normally put when using `.click()` tells it to only trigger that click even if the element being clicked matches that filter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're binding your click handler to the button that exists on the page when it loads for the first time, but when you re-load the DIV content that button is replaced with a new (unbound) one.

You're better off using [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

If you change your click handling code to the following it should work:

```
$('.inner-content').on('click', '.addNewRow', function() {

    // determine closest wrapper
    var wrapper = $(this).closest(".questions");
    var kategorieId = $(this).data("row");

    // add another row
    $("<div class='question_wrapper'><input type='text' class='textinput_questions new_question' data-category='"+kategorieId+"' name='new_question["+kategorieId+"][]'><input type='checkbox' class='radioinput' style='margin-left: 6px !important;' name='new_questionActive[]'>").insertAfter(".question_wrapper:last");
});
```

The above works because you're not removing/replacing the inner-content DIV itself, just the content within it.